# WP Как добавить комментарий в поле для Featured image?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, есть ли возможность для всех типов записей `post` в блоке `Featured image` добавить комментарий для контент менеджера, что-то по типу - `Загружай размером 1000х400px` *Только для постов.

[image: Комментарий для поста]

Попробовал предложеный вариант, с добавлением в `funtions.php`.

```
function add_featured_image_instruction($content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id)
{
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'post') {
        $comment = '<p class="featured-image-instruction">Загружайте изображения размером 1000х400px *Только для постов.</p>';
        $content .= $comment;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_image_instruction', 10, 3);
```

но для меня он не сработал. Комментарий не появляеться.

Comment: Можете использовать фильтр [admin_post_thumbnail_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_html/)

Comment: Да, попробовал. Но, почему-то не помогло. Сообственно о чём и написано в этой документации с новым Гутенбергом)

Comment: Тогда этот вариант должен подойти [editor.PostFeaturedImage](https://github.com/danielbachhuber/gutenberg-migration-guide/blob/master/filter-admin-post-thumbnail-html.md), по ссылке будет пример.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение. Это немного не, то что мне надо, но возможно получиться применить, хотя конечно рассчитывал на какой-то более простой вариант. Без переписывания JS-ом гутенберг блоков... Что по сути можно решить и банальным вбросом JS костылей в этот блок.

Comment: Насколько я понял, почитав обсуждения на гитхабе, варианта попроще на данный момент нет)

Comment: Панели формируются JS-кодом, никакие php-хуки не помогут. Надо трансформировать правильный код, ссылку на который дал @Simon.